# React and laravel mix : Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react '

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, jestjs, laravel-mix

I am learning unit testing using jest testing library in react js with laravel, here is what I have so far.

.babelrc file

```
{
    "plugins": [
      [
          "module-resolver",
          {
              "root": [
                  "./resources/js"
              ],
              "alias": {
                  "test": "./test"
              }
          }
      ]
  ],
"env": {
  "test": {
    "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-env", {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }],
      ["@babel/preset-react ", {
        "targets": {
          "node": "current"
        }
      }]
    ]
  },
  "development": {
    "presets": [
      ["env", {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 2%",
          "uglify": true
        }
      }]
    ]
  },
  "production": {
    "presets": [
      ["env", {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 2%",
          "uglify": true
        }
      }]
    ]
  }
}
}
```

package.json

```
{
  ............
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
    "jest": "^26.6.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^5.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

Now when I run `npm test`  I get the following error.

[image]

What do I need to do to solve this error?

Comment: are you able to share your learning repo as well?

Comment: @tmhao2005 unfortunately I cant :(  its just a react app with laravel ,

Comment: @tmhao2005 here is react laravel boiler plate https://github.com/huwcarwyn/react-laravel-boilerplate  u can use this one for testing

Comment: I've just quickly pulled and then run test but nothing doesn't work. Did you change anything or it doesn't work in case of original code from your end?

Comment: @tmhao2005 this is just boiler plate u can now just install jest, enzyme and try it to test by yourself , becuase the procedure is the same

Comment: @tmhao2005 you can use this tutorial : https://medium.com/@adiach3nko/how-to-configure-jest-testing-framework-for-laravel-mix-775a03b1c71

Comment: Hold on. The starter repo works fine from my end. So my question is did you change anything to make it stop working or it hasn't worked since you pulled this repo?

Comment: I mean I cant share my repo , but you can use the repo above to recreate the error by installing jest enzyme and  try to test it

Comment: Not sure why it would be error if just installing enzyme. But is that all to replicate your issue?

Comment: @tmhao2005 after installing enzyme u need to configure .babelrc  which u can find how to do it in the tutorial above, after configuring enzyme now run npm run test, u will get the error above,

Comment: I think the issue is most likely from the configuration itself. It's a bit weird from my point of view which I've never seen that before by nested env property. I think you can test that by keeping only value of test env and remove the others.

Comment: @tmhao2005 removing other parts I get this : ` Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
    If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.`

Comment: Can you share me what you have changed the configuration babelrc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223643/discussion-between-the-dead-man-and-tmhao2005).

Comment: The issue is with a test that is failing but I don't see the test file. Can you supply the test ?

Comment: I have solved the issue